# Find potential patents related / linked to a Trademark

Tags: software, patent-search, trademark

Apologies in advance if this isn't the right place to ask - I'm new to this forum.

I'm building a software product that is similar to an existing product online in some ways. I want to make sure I'm not investing time and money on something that cannot be used. I know there is a Trademark associated to the existing competitive product but I don't know if there are any patents granted for those similarities I'm going for.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting point for you is to see all the brochures, investor reports, annual reports and website of said company for relevant patent numbers. if you find them its good if not then you switch to patent search websites.

You have to check both utility patents and design patents if related integrated circuits too. the way to search will be searching by organization name as applicant or assignee, if nothing fruitful comes than switch to inventor names for which you can see annual report of organization.

you can use following links to search, please read help files to use database effectively:-

1. [European Patent Office](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/advancedSearch?locale=en_EP)
2. [US patent office](http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/index.html)